# Is it legal for google street view images to see in my house (EU)?

Tags: privacy, european-union, recording, google

My aunt lives somewhere on the territory of European Union and I navigated to her house in street view mode on Google Maps. I noticed that by navigating those images you can see into her house!

You can clearly see that she has a flower pot in the ground floor window. I mean, this doesn't create any problem, but what if she had a bathroom on that window and you could see her bathing?
[image]

Comment: One should recall that the images in google street view are single snapshots, not live images. In fact they often are not even in the current season. This significantly reduces any actual privacy issues. This does not, however, speak to the legal issue.

Comment: In the EU this is the subject of national law, not union law (or perhaps in addition to union law), which is why _street view coverage and related company policies are very different from one EU country to another._

Comment: This is not relevant to the law, but you can go into street view -> (3 dots icon by address) -> report a problem -> Request blurring (my house), and google should blur the house in question, if you're concerned about it.

Comment: @mbrig - That assumes you're happy to sign-up for a google account first.

Comment: @Kingsley no, it doesn't. You have to put your email into the form, but it works perfectly fine without being logged into anything

Comment: "My aunt lives somewhere on the territory of European Union" If you're concerned about privacy, you might want to remove the exact address on the screenshot you've posted.

Comment: @DavidSiegel how does that reduce the privacy issues? I don't want a photo of me using the toilet on the internet, thank you, and whether the photo is from today or last year makes no difference.

Comment: @terdon It reduces possible privacy issues because if the pic now up does not show a person using the bathroom, it will not do so in future, because the pics do not change. I rather suspect that pics are human-vetted before they go up, but I cannot confirm that.

Comment: Street view fairly consistently blurs faces, so I would suspect they deal with other privacy issues.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The pics may change over time as streets are re-driven and the imagery is updated (users can click the little clock icon to view the history of previous images and see how the location has changed over time), though the frequency at which this will happen depends on the location; in some major cities, it's not uncommon for some areas to be updated at least every year or so, while more remote locations may go many more years without a visit. Regardless, if someone using the bathroom is readily visible from the street, that's the fundamental issue.

Comment: You wouldn't be that much less specific if you'd written your aunt lives somewhere withing Solar System...

Comment: @terdon - if you can be seen on the toilet from the street you have more issues than a camera car going past every year or two. I hope you don't also live on a bus route ;)) Bus windows, even on single-deckers, are higher than Google cameras. Double-deckers can see in the 1st floor [US 2nd floor] too. I have privacy screens on the lower halves of all my front windows, so you can't even look in with your face pressed against the window, even at night.

Comment: Without necessarily needing to go into the legal aspects of this, I think it is going to be highly dependant on where you live as to how much of a concern this becomes. Anyone living in an urban area is so used to having to protect against being overlooked that this matter is already dealt with, long before Google decided to fix these images as a permanent record. If, however, you live in a dead-end street in a small village, you may feel that this exposure is so far outside your norm that it becomes a worry. At that point you start to ask 'is it legal?'.

Comment: @DavidSiegel well yes, of course, I didn't think Google had posted cameras outside every house, of course they're static. The point is that if the image they happened to capture is one you're not comfortable sharing, that can be a problem.

Comment: In March 2022, a Google Street View went viral. The reference was, "Find Bradworthy Inn, Holsworthy, UK.  Look 2 houses down at the house for sale."
The joke was that in the window you could see a man masturbating.  Google was quick to cover it up. However, I think the damage was done, because local people surely would know who lives there.
https://goo.gl/maps/wXC3Wpr6tKBRArC37

Answer (score 18):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

In Germany, taking pictures - and publishing them - is legal, if they're taken from public areas, from the general perspective of a passer-by, and if the picture doesn't make individual persons recognizable.

(There are some restrictions about making persons recognizable; if you take a picture of a monument or other building that would typically be photographed by tourists, and if the topic of the picture is clearly the monument, not a random bystander, then it's OK to publish even if the bystander's face is visible. But that doesn't work for individual's houses).

Still, Street View got into trouble because their cameras are mounted on roofs of a car, in a height of 2.5-3 meters, so they violated the "perspective of a passer-by" rule. To return to the example of "bathroom", the camera could well be able to see you nude when a passer-by would only be able to see a small portion of the ceiling next to the window.

Because of this, and because many Germans were uneasy with seeing their houses on the internet, as a condition to permit Street View at all, the German government insisted on allowing people to request their house to be removed; in 2010, approximately 250000 people made use of that (source: https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-11595495).

Because of the high resistance against Street View in Germany, Google published what they had in 2011, but stopped collecting more images. This is explained in https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/germany-street-view/, which also explains some of the reasons why Germans are so heavily biased for privacy.

Comment: *Google published what they had in 2011, but stopped collecting more images* Let's just say that they did not collect much by 2011: https://imgur.com/a/8Vsd1om :)

Comment: German angst in its best form.

Comment: @WoJ: It's worth noting that Apple Maps now offers a similar product which has much more extensive coverage, in almost every German city and even many villages. It's just that this time around, it wasn't widely reported, so there was no mass panic like a decade ago for Google Street View.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the height thing--it's taller than someone standing on the ground, sure, but a normal height for, e.g., passengers in a common coach bus.

Comment: @user3067860 Coach buses aren’t a normal thing in most German streets. It’s not something you would plan for with visual cover or your daily habits.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi OK, but cab over trucks? People on horseback? Etc. If the street view car is getting an eyefull then other people are probably inadvertently getting one, too.

Comment: @user3067860 Do they exist? Yes. Are they normal passer-bys in residential areas? No. If they get an eyeful, they better look the other way and don’t take pictures.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

In [R v Sotheren (2001) NSWSC 204](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/cases/nsw/supreme_ct/2001/204.html) Justice Dowd said **“A person, in our society, does not have a right not to be photographed.”**

The tort of breach of privacy requires a reasonable expectation of privacy. If it can be seen from the street, it isn’t private.

Comment: What about google earth satelite images

Comment: @BogdanFloareș "seen from the street" is not to be taken literally. A more literal phrasing would be "with a direct line of sight when standing in a public space". Low Earth orbit is a public space, so the overhead footage of your house is figuratively "seen from the street" in the way this answer intended it.

Comment: To be noted "reasonable expectation of privacy" is **NOT** a principle used in many countries, including many EU countries.It's an English/US thing.

Comment: @Flater Google Earth "satelite" images are not taken from Low Earth Orbit.  They are taken from aircraft.  (Actually, the country-scale images may be from orbit, but they have no privacy implications.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica and public airspace is public too, so it doesn't seem to matter to Flater's line of reasoning whether the photograph was taken from an airplane or a satellite.

Comment: @phoog - Correct.  I should have clarified that I wasn't criticizing his reasoning, just a minor detail in it.

Answer (score 5):

Dale M's answer is correct, but there's more:

> what if she had a bathroom on that window and you could see her bathing?

That could well lead to her being charged with public nudity / indecent exposure (depending on where exactly in Europe it is).

The fact that she would be exposing herself inside her house wouldn't matter: the fact that the public could easily see her from the street would. She would be aware of the visibility, and *not* taking steps to prevent it (e.g. privacy curtains) could well throw her into legal trouble.

Comment: You note "depending on where exactly in Europe this", but can I re-emphasize this more please.  The freedom to be naked in your own garden is a _bit_ of a grey area in Germany, but having a bathroom which it was possible to see into would not be.  Deliberately taking a photograph of someone in such a bathroom _would_ land you in hot water.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Oh really? So, one could put a tiny bathroom with transparent glass walls on their lawn right by the public walk and have nude showers in there so that passers-by could gaze their genitalia?

Comment: Probably.  That would be back into the "naked in your own garden" grey area.  (Again, photographers probably would be at risk of legal trouble.)  The Germans are a _lot_ more relaxed about nudity than a lot of places.

Comment: To chip in on this, i live in Belgium and the law states: "If you are visible for a passer-by without any effort from them, you CAN be charged." So if the passer-by has to jump for example, you are fine. But if they are just passing, and look to the right and see you naked. You could be in trouble.

Comment: "depending on where exactly in Europe it is". OP's example is in Romania.

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, the StreetView cars did not take images from the position of a passer-by but from a higher vantage point, so it's entirely possible they could e.g. see over a 2 meter fence.

Comment: indecent exposure does **not** cut inside a bathroom, especially not when the camera is at least a meter above people's normal view. Indecent exposure only cuts in places where you are reasonable in public, e.g. on your balcony or the garden, but not in the house.

Comment: Aside from the legal aspects, if someone can see you nude from the street and you haven't done anything to mitigate, you'd be rather hypocritical to complain about it.  Me, I'd call the architect an idiot.

Comment: @Trish The height is irrelevant. Consider a high rise block and the possibility that someone on the block opposite can see you naked. In Singapore even visible wearing underwear and being visible in public (you risk having to pay a fine not exceeding $2,000 or being sentenced to prison for a term not exceeding three months - or both.)

Comment: @DavidPostill that does not match with the German legal stance on the topic.

Comment: In which country in Europe you can still be charged with public nudity / indecent exposure in XXI century?

Comment: @DanubianSailor The Uk for starters. [uk indecent exposure law - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=uk+indecent+exposure+law)

Comment: @DavidPostill ok thx but it seems to have little to do with the OPs case, since the intention to be seen is a key factor.

Comment: @DanubianSailor If the OP's aunt can easily be seen by passerby in her own shower she'll have hard time convincing she didn't know. And if she knew and still exposed herself, that's intention.

Comment: In the UK, indecent exposure requires intent: it is defined as deliberately exposing your genitals with the intention of causing alarm or distress. If you think you can't be seen, you have a good defence.